# Duplicate Edge transport servers display in ECP

Tags: exchange-2016

I have Exchange 2016 with DAG configured in my environment. There are 2 DAG members and 1 Exchange Edge Transport Server.

Today I changed exchange certificate and assigned services to it, it gave me a warning to re-subscribe exchange edge in your site.

So I first remove previous subscription and apply new subscription on edge and mailbox servers. after re-subscribe exchange edge, there are now 2 entries being displayed under servers --> servers tab in ECP. one entry with proper edge transport server name and 2nd entry with CNF:95d1c2eb-********-ff9291471906. this entry is duplicate of edge transport server.

there are also duplicate entries under mail flow--> send connector. one entry is proper name, but second entry is duplicate with the same CNF which i mentioned above. For better understanding snapshots are attached.

edge duplicate entry:
[image: edge_duplicate_entry]

send connector duplicate:
[image: send_connector_duplicate]

Can anyone explain what is CNF entry? Can I delete it? Is this CNF duplicate entry harmful? please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to [this blog](https://www.itprotoday.com/active-directory/i-have-objects-my-active-directory-ad-domain-have-cnf-their-name-followed-globally) about “CNF:” object, it seems a duplicate object, I think you could delete one of them. And here is [a detailed article](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/15435.active-directory-duplicate-object-name-resolution.aspx?ranMID=24542&ranEAID=TnL5HPStwNw&ranSiteID=TnL5HPStwNw-q0ecfJXr6xNpD2dfN06a_w&epi=TnL5HPStwNw-q0ecfJXr6xNpD2dfN06a_w&irgwc=1&OCID=AID681541_aff_7593_1243925&tduid=(ir__bjtmzpr3nskfrhwi0h20wk909m2xmppbe2rd6a6o00)(7593)(1243925)(TnL5HPStwNw-q0ecfJXr6xNpD2dfN06a_w)()&irclickid=_bjtmzpr3nskfrhwi0h20wk909m2xmppbe2rd6a6o00).